# org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Forbidden [403] Spring boot soap call

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, spring-ws

We are getting below exception while trying to call a soap service through spring boot :    2.1.3.RELEASE
Class:

```
public class Client extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

@Autowired
private MessageSender messageSender ;
```

Request :

```
RequestTest request = new RequestTest ();
    request.setSRequestXML("XML CONTENT");
```

Client Method:

```
WebServiceTemplate serviceTemplate = getWebServiceTemplate();
        serviceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender);
        ResponseTest response = (ResponseTest) serviceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(url, request,
                new SoapActionCallback(callBack));
```

Below error is on last line above :

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Forbidden [403]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
```

Any thoughts please help

Comment: Apparently, the soap service your are calling won't permit you to do that:  *"The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.  This status is similar to 401, but for the 403 Forbidden status code, re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource."* (source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Comment: So ... basically ... you need to figure out *why* it is not permitted.  I don't know how we can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC, the same code is working older versions of spring boot , but sure ill give a try where this is happening.